# I need to use multiple Strings created in a method inside a class in a different class

Tags: java, class, methods, split, void

So basically i have a method in a class, lets say Class A, that when you give it a String,
uses a Split, to create multiple strings. This method would be something like this:

```
Public void xxxx(String entry){

     String[] Parts=entry.split(" ");
     String part1=Parts[0]; 
     String part2=Parts[1];
```

So now, i want to use this two strings, inside an if(....) in a different class, how do i do it?
I need each parts (there are more than 2) in different if, and sometimes all together so, how do i use them? thanks

Comment: That is obviously not valid Java, including the `Public` instead of `public`.  Please don't post kind-of/sort-of code. Post real code that best exemplifies your problem. As for a solution, you could have the method return the String array rather than assign it to local variables, variables that can't be used anywhere else.

Comment: You might want to consider whether it's even worth having the `xxxx` method at all. Anywhere you were thinking of calling `xxxx`, you could just write the `split` call instead.

Comment: It really doesn't seem necessary to wrap `split()`. I assume your real problem is more complex; perhaps you should give more realistic code, so we can better understand your needs and provide alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm for sure posting my real code next time, it was my first time doing a question here. I copy-pasted this idea from another website and i didnt even realize what it was doing, it makes more sense to not create those variables. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear from your description how these classes and methods work together.  But since all your `xxxx` method does is split strings it would be best to make it a static utility class.

Then you can do something like this.

```java
class MyClass {
     // Note that this method doesn't really add any benefit to
     // simply using String.split().
     public static String[] xxxx(String entry){
        String[] parts=entry.split(" ");
        return parts;
     }
}

class OtherClass {
    public void someMethod(String str) {
        String[] p = MyClass.xxxx(str);
        System.out.println(p[0]);
        System.out.println(p[1]);
    }
}
```

There are many other possibilities.  It all depends on how you want methods and classes to interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1) Return a String array. (Not terribly useful method if this is all you are doing.)

```
public String[] xxxx(String entry) {
  String[] Parts=entry.split(" ");
  return parts;
}
```

2) Return an instance of an object that provides access to the various String parts.

```
public class PartHolder{
  private ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getPartsCount() {
        return parts.size();
    }

    public String getPart(int x) {
        return parts.get(x);
    }

    public void addPart(String part) {
        parts.add(part);
    }

    public void addParts(String[] partsToAdd) {
        parts.addAll(Arrays.asList(partsToAdd));
    }
}
...
public String[] xxxx(String entry) {
  String[] Parts=entry.split(" ");
  return parts;
}
```

3) Make the String parts accessible through a globally accessible (static) method or attribute.  This approach has limited utility since there is added complexity when dealing with multi-threaded applications.

```
public static String[] GLOBAL_PARTS;
public void xxxx(String entry) {
  GLOBAL_PARTS = entry.split(" ");
}
```